# How do I use XSLT to add a new element in output document?

Tags: xslt

I have input document. It;s a table with one col:

```
<table>
<tr><td>0</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td></tr>
</table>
```

The number in first row is number of parents of `<li>` elements in output document. It's variously. I need to generate structure in ouput document like this:

```
<li id="0">
 <li id="1">
  <li id="2"/>
 </li>
 <li id="3">
  <li id="4"/>
  <li id="5"/>
 </li>
</li>
```

Do I do the link to element in out-document to append child? May be I need recursion algorithm...

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you explain, step by step, the logic that needs to be applied in order to get from the input to the output? -- P.S. I don't think `li` elements can be nested.

Comment: Ok) We have a table with numbers, for example, 0, 1, 0, 3, 3, or 0, 1, 2, 2 - any count of rows. This is description of the tree nesting structure that needs to result. For the firts table: the first and the third elements mast be root. The next element mast be inserted in the first element. The fourth mast be inserted in third, and fifth - in third. For the other table: the first element is root. The next element mast be inserted in the first element. The third elements mast be inserted in the next element. The fourth - in the next element too.

Comment: I am afraid this still makes no sense to me. There are 5 nodes in your input, and 6 in your output.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you could do is use a key, to associate `tr` elements by the first preceding sibling that has a lower `td` value

```
 <xsl:key name="lists" match="tr" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::tr[td &lt; current()/td][1])" />
```

To get the top-level elements, you would do this...

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('lists', generate-id())" />
```

And when positioned on a `tr` element, to get the child elements for that, you would do this...

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('lists', generate-id())" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="lists" match="tr" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::tr[td &lt; current()/td][1])" />

    <xsl:template match="/table">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('lists', '')" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tr">
        <li id="{td}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('lists', generate-id())" />
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I don't believe `<li>` tags should be nested in this way. They should really be contained in `<ol>` or `<ul>` tags, for a start. Perhaps this is what you really meant....

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="lists" match="tr" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::tr[td &lt; current()/td][1])" />

    <xsl:template match="/table">
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('lists', '')" />
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tr">
        <li id="{td}">
            <xsl:if test="key('lists', generate-id())">
                <ul>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('lists', generate-id())" />
                </ul>
            </xsl:if>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```