# XSLT recursion for tree generation

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

We have input document, that describe structure of a tree:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<html>
<mas>
    <row> <col>2</col><col>4</col>  </row>
    <row> <col>3</col> </row>
    <row> <col></col> </row>
    <row> <col>5</col><col>6</col>  </row>
    <row> <col></col> </row>
    <row> <col></col> </row>
 </mas>
</html>
```

We want to create a tree.
We want output document like this:

```xml
<Transform id="b_1">
 <Transform id="b_2">
  <Transform id="b_3"/>
 </Transform>
 <Transform id="b_4">
  <Transform id="b_5"/>
  <Transform id="b_6"/>
 </Transform>
</Transform>
```

I have XSLT stylesheet:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<xsl:template name="vetka">
 <xsl:param name="row"/> 
 <xsl:for-each select="html/mas/*[$row]/*" >  
  <xsl:variable name="col" select="position()"/>
  <xsl:variable name="num" select="//html/mas/*[$row]/*[$col]"/>
  <Transform>   
   <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="concat('b_',$num)"/></xsl:attribute>   
   <xsl:call-template name="vetka">
    <xsl:with-param name="row" select="$num"/>
   </xsl:call-template>
  </Transform>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:result-document href="str.txt">
  <xsl:call-template name="vetka">
   <xsl:with-param name="row" select='1'/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But we get two  ("b_2","b_4"). I think, recursion is not start. Why?

Comment: How is this different from your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40232243/how-do-i-use-xslt-to-add-a-new-element-in-output-document ?

Comment: This is about recursion. It's not start(

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is with this line...

```
<xsl:for-each select="html/mas/*[$row]/*" >
```

This works first time, because you are positioned on the document elememt `/`. But when you recursively call the template, you are now positioned on a `col` element, and this `xsl:for-each` will look for a child element of that called `html`. So, you should change it to this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/html/mas/*[$row]/*" />
```

Also, when you recursively call the template, the `row` parameter needs to be set to a number. At the moment it is a string (a string that happens to contain a number).

Try this XSLT, which I have simplified a bit (because your `num` variable was actually just the value of the current `col` element)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template name="vetka">
 <xsl:param name="row"/> 
 <xsl:for-each select="//html/mas/*[$row]/*[. != '']" >  
  <xsl:variable name="num" select="."/>
  <Transform id="{concat('b_',$num)}">   
   <xsl:call-template name="vetka">
    <xsl:with-param name="row" select="number($num)"/>
   </xsl:call-template>
  </Transform>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:call-template name="vetka">
   <xsl:with-param name="row" select='1'/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This doesn't quite produce the output you want, but I couldn't work out where your `b_1` comes from.